# Installing packages and tools on a local non-standard directory

Tags: shell, compiling, environment-variables

**TLDR:** What environment variables should I update to guarantee that my system has access to everything a package provides when building it on a non-traditional path?

I usually don't have root access to the system where I work, so I install my packages on local folder under my home directory:

```
~/my_installations/
```

Over time, this creates the typical folder hierarchy that includes

```
bin
lib
man
share
info
include
```

among others.

In order to properly provide access to the corresponding binaries and libraries after installation, I update `PATH` to include `~/my_installations/bin` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `~/my_installations/lib`.

However, how can I provide implicit access to the rest of the material under my build path ? What other environment variables should I update to have everything else available to command line tools and my system in general? (e.g. `include` paths, `man` pages, etc.).

Is there a general set of standards or guide for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update [`MANPATH`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_manpath.htm) (as well as [`INFOPATH`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPath)) to point at your personal directory's man pages.  Unfortunately, there's no single way to tell software to also look in your include paths.  You might have to set `CFLAGS` (but not always) or other variable used in the build system.